# find the volume of the solid of intersection of the two spheres of radii a and b (with b $<$ a)

Tags: calculus, integration, cross-sections

Also the center of the smaller one lies on the surface of the larger one.

This is what I have thus far.

Utilize the Cartesian plane we have for the smaller and larger spheres respectively:
$(x-a)^2 + y^2 = b^2 $ and $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$

I solve for the $x$ value where these 2 intersect. I get $x_r = \frac{2a^2 - b^2}{2a}$

To get the volume of the larger cap in the intersection I used the method of cross sections.
$\int^{a}_{x_r} \pi(a^2 - x^2)dx$

Similarly for the smaller sphere: $\int^{b}_{x_r} \pi(b^2 - (x-a)^2)dx$

Afterwards, I sum the result of the two to get the answer? Did I make a mistake somewhere

Comment: Is a $+z^2$ missing from the left-hand side of each sphere's definition?

Comment: @J.G. Well my strategy involved taking everything to 2 dimensions on the $xy$ plane. Then work my way back up to 3 dimensions using the method of cross sections.

Comment: That strategy works, with some care. If you write $(x-a)^2+y^2=b^2-z^2$ etc., you can write the cross-section at a given $z$ as a function of $z$, then integrate over $z$.

Comment: @J.G. I don't follow. I understand the equation you put is the sphere with the $z$ variable present on the right. How would the function of $z$ for cross section look?

Comment: I'll explain it in an answer, on the assumption the circles have respective centres $(a,\,0,\,0),\,(0,\,0,\,0)$. Let me know if you intended something different.

Comment: @J.G. much thanks! That assumption I accept and is really the one I made above with 2 dimensions.

Comment: I've posted an answer that explains the point I was making. Unfortunately, it turns out not to be an especially tractable approach. I'll try to find a better one using another coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. You are basically taking $x$ as your $z$ axis and hence in cylindrical coordinates $y^2 + z^2 = r^2$ and so you may want to write them as,

$r^2+x^2 = a^2$ and $r^2 + (x-a)^2 = b^2$.

Your first integral is fine but your second integral should be

$\displaystyle \int_{a-b}^{\frac{2a^2 - b^2}{2a}} \pi \, \big(b^2 - (a-x)^2\big) \,dx = \frac{\pi b^6}{24a^3} - \frac{\pi b^4}{2a} + \frac{2 \pi b^3}{3}$

The lower bound is the minimum value of $x$ for the smaller sphere, which is $(a-b)$ and it is part of the intersection volume.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If the circles of radii $b,\,a$ have respective centres $(a,\,0,\,0),\,(0,\,0,\,0)$, their intersection is confined to $|z|\le b<a$. For such $z$, the intersection satisfies$$0\le(x-a)^2+y^2\le b^2-z^2,\,0\le x^2+y^2\le a^2-z^2.$$Rewriting the $xy$-plane with polar coordinates, the first double inequality is$$\begin{align}(r-a\cos\theta)^2&\le b^2-z^2-a^2\sin^2\theta\\\iff r&\in\left[a\cos\theta-\sqrt{b^2-z^2-a^2\sin^2\theta},\,a\cos\theta+\sqrt{b^2-z^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}\right],\end{align}$$which is satisfiable iff $\sin^2\theta\le\frac{b^2-z^2}{a^2}$. The second sphere's double inequality is equivalent to $0\le r\le\sqrt{a^2-z^2}$. So the intersection is$$\begin{align}|\theta|&\le\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{b^2-z^2}}{a},\\r&\in\left[\max\left\{0,\,a\cos\theta-\sqrt{b^2-z^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}\right\},\,\min\left\{\sqrt{a^2-z^2},\,a\cos\theta+\sqrt{b^2-z^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}\right\}\right].\end{align}$$If we right this more concisely as $-f(z)\le\theta\le f(z),\,g_-(\theta)\le r\le g_+(\theta)$, the volume of the intersection is$$\int_{-b}^bdz\int_{-f}^fd\theta\int_{-g}^grdr.$$

Comment: "Tractable" would be an understatement. While I don't see anything wrong with you presented and I follow your reasoning.

My original question is taken from Calculus Early Transcendentals 7th Edition by Edwards and Penny.

The answer is $\frac{\pi b^3(8a-3b)}{12a}$

Comment: @Malcolm Sorry. My first comment on this page served to explain how the third dimension complicates ideas you were trying to carry over from two dimensions, in ways you may not have appreciated. I hope I've at least done some good there. Unfortunately, I subsequently found that neither my answer's use of cylindrical coordinates nor an alternative use of spherical coordinates is useful to solve the problem. The approach you should use turns out to be [this one](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html), which I'll try to edit into my answer later.

Comment: Lol. What a coincidence that the same Wolfram page is one I've been trying to apply for a while now. Don't worry I appreciate your assistance in this problem. We just knocked out options that wouldn't help us, that's all :)

Comment: @Malcolm Part of me wonders whether an intersection/union conflation is causing trouble here, becuse the case $R=d=a,\,r=b$ of their calculations doesn't give Edwards & Penny's formula.

Comment: I think a key difference is the fact that the center of 1 lies on the surface of the other. With this text, I've never found the questions complicated, just a key difference or trick where you have to adjust the general solution formula.